# Generating unique numbers that pass Luhn algorithm verification

Tags: php, algorithm

I am trying to generate unique numbers that can be verified with Luhn algorithm. The aim is to provide account numbers, so to speak, for all members on a p2p lending platform. I've been looking into luhn algorithm and a couple of other check digit algorithms, but all the information I get is on verifying numbers with these algorithms but I'm looking for pointers on actually generating those numbers which will pass this check digit algorithm. I'm using PHP for the project.

Any pointers or recommendation is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: https://github.com/gxela/creditcard-number-generator might be handy

Comment: The Luhn algorithm generates an additional checksum digit for an arbitrary number. Can't you just generate a number and then append the check digit? The explanation on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) should be sufficient to generate such a check digit.

Comment: @MOehm: That looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @rici: I was a bit reluctant to answer, because I don't really know PHP, but I've given it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I guess I didn't really understand the concept of a check-digit algorithm. But i get it now. I have to generate my own unique numbers and then "luhnify" it by added an extra digit to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Luhn algorithm generates an additional checksum digit for an arbitrary number. That means that you can turn any number with *n* digits into a Luhn-compatible number with *n* + 1 digits.

The [Wikipedia article on the Luhn algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) explains how to generate such a check digit: Set the rightmost digit, the check digit, to zero. Work from right to left and add the digits. Alternate between the digit itself and the digitsum of two times the digit. Now determine the check digit so that the whole sum's last digit is zero.

If you have a unique number you can make it Luhn compatible with:

```
function luhnify($number) {
    $sum = 0;               // Luhn checksum w/o last digit
    $even = true;           // Start with an even digit
    $n = $number;

    // Lookup table for the digitsums of 2*$i
    $evendig = array(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9);

    while ($n > 0) {
        $d = $n % 10;
        $sum += ($even) ? $evendig[$d] : $d;

        $even = !$even;
        $n = ($n - $d) / 10;
    }

    $sum = 9*$sum % 10;

    return 10 * $number + $sum; 
}
```

This code uses a number as input. Take care not to overflow the allowable range of numbers, because the Luhnified number will be 10 times as large as the original number.

A better solution would be to use a string of digits, but I'm not really familiar with PHP, so I've chosen the easier way with numbers.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. The check digit is generated correctly. Though the luhnified number is not 10 times as large as the original number.

Comment: Why not? It has one more digit appended to its end. (I mean "large" in the numerical sense: 50 is 10 times as large as 5, but it is is only one digit longer.)